# How to change language in Ubuntu Gnome's lock screen?

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, language-support, screensaver, input-language

I've recently switched to using the Gnome desktop environment, and most things work smoothly. However, I have two languages installed on my machine(Persian and English) and whenever the screen gets locked while the keyboard is set to Persian, I can't find a way to switch it back to English to unlock the screen. The only way I know of, is to restart the computer.

Searching the internet the only questionable "workaround" I could find was to purge `gnome-screensaver` and install `xscreensaver`. But this is not a real solution, because you still can't change the input language, all you can do is kill `xscreensaver` from one of the non-graphical "virtual terminals".

### Edit

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit. Running the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` outputs:

```
[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ir')]
```

Also, running `cat /etc/default/keyboard` returns:

```
# Check /usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/README.Debian for
# documentation on what to do after having modified this file.

# The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
# values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
# in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ir"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"

# If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can
# specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible
# before /usr is mounted.
# KMAP=/etc/console-setup/defkeymap.kmap.gz
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

### Workaround:

As mentioned in the comments by Gunnar Hjalmarsson, one can avoid this problem if they switch from LightDM to GDM3.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Absolutely.

Comment: Did you set a custom shortcut to change between them?

Comment: One more question: Did you swich to the GDM display manager, or are you still using LightDM?

Comment: @MuaadElSharif As you can see from the output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard` , the toggle for switching language is `Alt`+`Shift` which I believe is the default settings.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I'm still using LightDM.

Comment: Then switching to GDM might be worth a try.

Comment: Also, <Alt>+<Shift> is not default. <Super>+<Space> is.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Oh, then I guess I've changed that 4 years ago or so. I'm looking into switching to GDM.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson OK, so after switching to gdm3 the issue does not consist any more.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently some issues with using Ubuntu's default display manager LightDM together with GNOME shell. So switching from LightDM to GNOME's GDM might help.

Answer (score 1):

I was frustrated for so long with this issue. I ended up writing a custom script that will make sure to automatically switch my locale to English every time my screen locks.

The basic script is as follows:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | \
(
  while true; do
    read X
    if echo $X | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; then
      setxkbmap us;
    fi
  done
)
```

Note that this is working on most versions of Ubuntu, including the most recent one (as of the time of writing), but for some you need to tweak it a bit. Check [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/how-to-run-a-script-on-screen-lock-unlock), if this is not your command.

I saved this script in a file `language.sh`, added it as executable script (`sudo chmod +x language.sh`) and then added it to the startup applications from System > Preferences > Startup Applications.

Hopefully this will spare some nerves to other users too!